# JavaScript function to convert UTF8 string between fullwidth and halfwidth forms

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, character, converters

EDIT: Thanks to `GOTO 0`, I now know exactly what I my question is called.

I need a JavaScript function to convert [from UTF-8 fullwidth form to halfwidth form](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms/utf8test.htm).

Comment: Javascript strings already handle unicode so what problem are you actually trying to solve?  Do you really need to process binary data yourself in javascript?

Comment: That's not "decoding" so much as "mapping." Why do you need to do this at all? This smells like [an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242)

Comment: Whatever you call it, whether "decoding" or "mapping", you can tell that `！ａｂｃ　ＡＢＣ！` is different from `!abc ABC!`, and this conversion function IS what I'm asking for.

Comment: There is no straightforward conversion function for this, and building one can be complex. There is not always an inherent connection between different Unicode characters that look almost the same, like `ａ` and `a`  That's why it's really worth looking at why you need this in the first place, there may be an easier way

Comment: ... but if you really just want to replace that specific range of characters, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace should do (use the actual characters in an UTF-8 encoded HTML file and you should be fine)

Comment: I don't understand why building one that does `- U+FF00 + 0x20`  
in Javascript can be complex. It's straightforward for me in C. PS. I'm asking for `- U+FF00 + 0x20`, not regex replacement.

Comment: My request has nothing to do with HTML or HTML file. It's pure javascript function implementation.

Comment: Probably this string is encoded in UTF16 and not in UTF8 (ASCII chars in UTF8 are encoded exactly as plain ASCII)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
function toASCII(chars) {
    var ascii = '';
    for(var i=0, l=chars.length; i<l; i++) {
        var c = chars[i].charCodeAt(0);

        // make sure we only convert half-full width char
        if (c >= 0xFF00 && c <= 0xFFEF) {
           c = 0xFF & (c + 0x20);
        }

        ascii += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }

    return ascii;
}

// example
toASCII("ＡＢＣ"); // returns 'ABC' 0x41
```

Comment: Thanks you Rezigned. Can you add a loop to deal with *string* please? I'd assume looping with your function would still be faster than the regexp replace.

Answer (score 21):

Apperently, you want to convert [halfwidth and fullwidth form](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms/utf8test.htm) characters to their equivalent basic latin forms. If this is correct, you can do a replacement using a regular expression. Something like this should work:

```
var x = "！ａｂｃ　ＡＢＣ！";
var y = x.replace(
    /[\uff01-\uff5e]/g,
    function(ch) { return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) - 0xfee0); }
    );
```

Where x is your input string and y is the output.

Comment: thank you. Would this regexp replace be faster than a for loop?

Comment: @xpt It surely is on my browser. I made a test jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/K9b56/. You can also change the input string to fit your requirements and see how both methods perform.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for the neat solution and proof (>10x faster, amazing). I believe everyone would choose this solution. But for myself, for educational purpose, I'll choose Rezigned's as the answer. I wish I can choose more than one as the answer. Thanks again. I believe other people would benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 14):

## Year 2018 answer

Many years later – and it’s still impossible to find on the Internet a function that does this. So I wrote mine. (Nearly learned Japanese and Korean to get to this point.)

### Simple version

Latin range only.

```
var shiftCharCode = Δ => c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + Δ);
var toFullWidth = str => str.replace(/[!-~]/g, shiftCharCode(0xFEE0));
var toHalfWidth = str => str.replace(/[！-～]/g, shiftCharCode(-0xFEE0));
```

### Complete version

Let me know if I missed any character.

```js
(function () {
    let charsets = {
        latin: {halfRE: /[!-~]/g, fullRE: /[！-～]/g, delta: 0xFEE0},
        hangul1: {halfRE: /[ﾡ-ﾾ]/g, fullRE: /[ᆨ-ᇂ]/g, delta: -0xEDF9},
        hangul2: {halfRE: /[ￂ-ￜ]/g, fullRE: /[ᅡ-ᅵ]/g, delta: -0xEE61},
        kana: {delta: 0,
            half: "｡｢｣､･ｦｧｨｩｪｫｬｭｮｯｰｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜﾝﾞﾟ", 
            full: "。「」、・ヲァィゥェォャュョッーアイウエオカキクケコサシ" + 
                "スセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワン゛゜"},
        extras: {delta: 0,
            half: "¢£¬¯¦¥₩\u0020|←↑→↓■°", 
            full: "￠￡￢￣￤￥￦\u3000￨￩￪￫￬￭￮"}
    };
    let toFull = set => c => set.delta ? 
        String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + set.delta) : 
        [...set.full][[...set.half].indexOf(c)];
    let toHalf = set => c => set.delta ? 
        String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) - set.delta) : 
        [...set.half][[...set.full].indexOf(c)];
    let re = (set, way) => set[way + "RE"] || new RegExp("[" + set[way] + "]", "g");
    let sets = Object.keys(charsets).map(i => charsets[i]);
    window.toFullWidth = str0 => 
        sets.reduce((str,set) => str.replace(re(set, "half"), toFull(set)), str0);
    window.toHalfWidth = str0 => 
        sets.reduce((str,set) => str.replace(re(set, "full"), toHalf(set)), str0);
})();

/* Example starts here: */
var set = prompt("Enter a couple of comma-separated strings (half or full-width):", 
    ["aouäöü123", "'\"?:", "¢£¥₩↑→", "ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ", "ﾡﾢￂￃ"].join()).split(",");
var steps = [set, set.map(toFullWidth), set.map(toFullWidth).map(toHalfWidth)];
var tdHTML = str => `<td>${str}</td>`;
var stepsHTML = steps.map(step => step.map(tdHTML).join(""));
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
[...rows].forEach((row,i) => row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", stepsHTML[i]));
```

```css
th, td {border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 0.2em;}
th {text-align: left;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th scope="row">Input:</th></tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">Full-width:</th></tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">Half-width:</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that the Hangul maps in my code are faulty due to some gaps in Unicode (broken 1:1 mapping). Hang on until I fix them (not today) – or fix them on your own. Or just delete the `hangul1` and `hangul2` entries entirely as a temporary measure.

Answer (score 3):

[The answer of GOTO 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20488304/9265131) is very useful, but I also need convert **space** from fullwidth to halfwidth.

So below is my code:

```js
const halfwidthValue = value
      .replace(/[\uff01-\uff5e]/g, fullwidthChar => String.fromCharCode(fullwidthChar.charCodeAt(0) - 0xfee0))
      .replace(/\u3000/g, '\u0020');
```

Answer (score 1):

The given solutions do not work for all the cases of Full-Width to Half-Width conversion of Kana (eg. デジタル　is not converted properly). I have made a function for converting Zenkaku to Hankaku Katakana, Hope it helps.

```
function convertToHalfWidth(string) {
  let characters = getCharacters(string);
  let halfWidthString = ''
  characters.forEach(character => {
    halfWidthString += mapToHankaku(character);
  });
  return halfWidthString;
}

function getCharacters(string) {
   return string.split("");
}

function mapToHankaku(character) {
  let zenHanMap = getZenkakuToHankakuMap();
  if (typeof zenHanMap[character] === 'undefined') {
    return character;
  } else {
    return zenHanMap[character];
  }
}

function getZenkakuToHankakuMap() {
  let zenHanMap = {
    'ァ': 'ｧ',
    'ア': 'ｱ',
    'ィ': 'ｨ',
    'イ': 'ｲ',
    'ゥ': 'ｩ',
    'ウ': 'ｳ',
    'ェ': 'ｪ',
    'エ': 'ｴ',
    'ォ': 'ｫ',
    'オ': 'ｵ',
    'カ': 'ｶ',
    'ガ': 'ｶﾞ',
    'キ': 'ｷ',
    'ギ': 'ｷﾞ',
    'ク': 'ｸ',
    'グ': 'ｸﾞ',
    'ケ': 'ｹ',
    'ゲ': 'ｹﾞ',
    'コ': 'ｺ',
    'ゴ': 'ｺﾞ',
    'サ': 'ｻ',
    'ザ': 'ｻﾞ',
    'シ': 'ｼ',
    'ジ': 'ｼﾞ',
    'ス': 'ｽ',
    'ズ': 'ｽﾞ',
    'セ': 'ｾ',
    'ゼ': 'ｾﾞ',
    'ソ': 'ｿ',
    'ゾ': 'ｿﾞ',
    'タ': 'ﾀ',
    'ダ': 'ﾀﾞ',
    'チ': 'ﾁ',
    'ヂ': 'ﾁﾞ',
    'ッ': 'ｯ',
    'ツ': 'ﾂ',
    'ヅ': 'ﾂﾞ',
    'テ': 'ﾃ',
    'デ': 'ﾃﾞ',
    'ト': 'ﾄ',
    'ド': 'ﾄﾞ',
    'ナ': 'ﾅ',
    'ニ': 'ﾆ',
    'ヌ': 'ﾇ',
    'ネ': 'ﾈ',
    'ノ': 'ﾉ',
    'ハ': 'ﾊ',
    'バ': 'ﾊﾞ',
    'パ': 'ﾊﾟ',
    'ヒ': 'ﾋ',
    'ビ': 'ﾋﾞ',
    'ピ': 'ﾋﾟ',
    'フ': 'ﾌ',
    'ブ': 'ﾌﾞ',
    'プ': 'ﾌﾟ',
    'ヘ': 'ﾍ',
    'ベ': 'ﾍﾞ',
    'ペ': 'ﾍﾟ',
    'ホ': 'ﾎ',
    'ボ': 'ﾎﾞ',
    'ポ': 'ﾎﾟ',
    'マ': 'ﾏ',
    'ミ': 'ﾐ',
    'ム': 'ﾑ',
    'メ': 'ﾒ',
    'モ': 'ﾓ',
    'ャ': 'ｬ',
    'ヤ': 'ﾔ',
    'ュ': 'ｭ',
    'ユ': 'ﾕ',
    'ョ': 'ｮ',
    'ヨ': 'ﾖ',
    'ラ': 'ﾗ',
    'リ': 'ﾘ',
    'ル': 'ﾙ',
    'レ': 'ﾚ',
    'ロ': 'ﾛ',
    'ヮ': '',
    'ワ': 'ﾜ',
    // 'ヰ': 'ﾞ  ﾟ',
    // 'ヱ': '',
    'ヲ': 'ｦ',
    'ン': 'ﾝ',
    'ヴ': 'ｳﾞ',
    // 'ヵ': '',
    // 'ヶ': '',
    // 'ヷ': '',
    // 'ヸ': '',
    // 'ヹ': '',
    // 'ヺ': '',
    '・': '･',
    'ー': 'ｰ',
    // 'ヽ': '',
    // 'ヾ': '',
    // 'ヿ': '',
  };
  return zenHanMap;
}
```

Use as follows `convertToHalfWidth('デジタル');`

You can pass the result of this function to the function mentioned by `GOTO 0` and get the complete Half width result for the Japanese Language

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Unicode