# IBM Watson double-byte string conversion

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, double-byte

In IBM's documentation for text-to-speech feature there is an example of adding words to Japanese custom model:

[Adding words to a Japanese custom model](https://www.urldecoder.org/)

They say the following:

> The following examples of the PUT /v1/customizations/{customization_id}/words/{word} method translate the URL-encoded, double-byte string for NY to the noun (Mesi) ニューヨーク (New York in English). If this custom translation is not defined, the string is read as enu wai.

And provided example:

> curl -X PUT -u "apikey:{apikey}"
>   --header "Content-Type: application/json"
>   --data "{\"translation\":\"ニューヨーク\", \"part_of_speech\":\"Mesi\"}"
>   "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/customizations/{customization_id}/words/%EF%BC%AE%EF%BC%B9"

The question is:
**How to convert a string to its double-byte representation (nodejs)?**

I was playing with https://www.urldecoder.org/ but wasn't able to determine correct encoding... :(

Comment: I've found solution here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486551/javascript-function-to-convert-utf8-string-between-fullwidth-and-halfwidth-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486551/javascript-function-to-convert-utf8-string-between-fullwidth-and-halfwidth-forms)